# JSONKit Crash: iOS7 Xcode 5.1 in iPad ratina 64 bit device simulator

Tags: ios, json, nsstring, 64-bit, nsdictionary

I have used [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit) library to parse dictionary and get `JSON` string. All is well and good with normal devices (iOS7). But when i run application in iOS 7-64 bit simulator it was crashed at below method:

```
- (NSString *)JSONString;
```

And the crash message shows on this line of `JSONKit.m` class

[image]

Tried to find out it but not able to sort out.

And i ended up with our native [NSJSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/foundation/reference/nsjsonserialization_class/Reference/Reference.html) class.

Did any one sort out this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know there are more than one patch versions that tried to fix the 64 bit crash issue you mention here, e.g. [JSONKit 64bit crash fix by heroims](https://github.com/heroims/JSONKit).

They all tried to fix that troublesome line for getting **tagged pointers**, "the very first thing that a pointer to an Objective-C object "points to" is a pointer to that objects class":

```
*((void **)objectPtr)
```

I wrote a simple code to emulate the crash,

```
NSDictionary *dic = @{@"hi":@(4)};
void *keys[2], *objects[2];
CFDictionaryGetKeysAndValues((CFDictionaryRef)dic, (const void **)keys, (const void **)objects);
void *objectPtr = objects[0];
void *another = *((void **)objectPtr);//Only works for 32 bit machine
NSLog(@"%@",[another description]);
```

My guess is that for 64bit compiler, apple changed the tagged pointer implementation for NSNumber, which causes the crash. Check the discussion for tagged pointers here [stackoverflow.com/questions/5819387/why-is-nsnumber-immutable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5819387/why-is-nsnumber-immutable)

If I change `NSDictionary *dic = @{@"hi":@(4)};` to `NSDictionary *dic = @{@"hi":@"hello"};` it won't crash.

The patch I mentioned here just used object_getClass, which seems to defeat the original purpose, "Why not just use `object_getClass()`?..." (the comments right above)

So like you said now I also end up using NSJSONSerialization class.

Answer (score 2):

There is an patched version of JSONKit [here](https://github.com/jcbertin/JSONKit) that fixes the 64 bit issues among others.